How to navigate to a GoRouter ShellRoute instead of its sub routes? (Nested ShellRoute)
Question

With GoRouter, how to navigate to a ShellRoute, and therefore activate the lastly active route of this ShellRoute, without knowing it in advance?

Context
I use GoRouter for my Desktop Application.  At root, I have 2 StatefulShellRoute branches:

Projects
Team

In each branch I have routes. In Team, I have for example:

teamHome
maiteMarketPlace
maiteRouteSystem

maiteRouteSystem is a ShellRoute, with sub routes inside:

maiteDashboard
maiteQuickChat

Both maiteDashboard and maiteQuickChat need a pathParameter :maiteId, so they are scoped by Maite objects. See definition of the ShellRoute and its sub-routes:
static final ShellRoute maiteRouteSystem = ShellRoute(
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
      return NoTransitionPage(child: MaitePage(state: state, child: child));
    },
    routes: <RouteBase>[maiteDashboard],
  );

  static final NamedGoRoute maiteDashboard = NamedGoRoute(
    name: "maiteDashboard",
    path: '/team/:maiteId',
    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
      String? maiteId = state.pathParameters['maiteId'];
      return ... // my MaiteDashboardWidget
    },
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      maiteQuickChat,
    ],
  );

  static final NamedGoRoute maiteQuickChat = NamedGoRoute(
    name: "maiteQuickChat",
    path: 'quickChat',
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
      String? maiteId = state.pathParameters['maiteId'];
      return NoTransitionPage(
          child: ... // My MaiteQuickChat widget here... ,
      );
    },
  );

I want to...
Let's say I am outside the maiteRouteSystem's subroutes, i.e in teamHome. I want to activate the last route of the maiteRouteSystem ShellRoute for a given maite, let's say:

last time for the maite bobby I was on the maiteQuickChat, so I want to land on this route when I go on the maiteRouteSystem with path parameter :bobby .
last time for the maite sarah I was on the maiteDashboard, so I want to land on this route when I go on the maiteRouteSystem with path parameter :sarah .

State Management is not a good solution
I already know how to do it with State Management (i.e Riverpod). However, I believe this solution is not best practice as navigation should be solely for Router, not for state management.
As you can see, maiteQuickChat and maiteDashboard are 2 distinct routes, so I would like to keep targeting each individually (easy), or to target the ShellRoute itself and therefore only fall on the last route used in this shell.
Thank you very much for your help!
